# What does it mean for a shape to be "broadcastible" to another in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I'm trying to replicate numpy behavior in another library.  One of the things my library is missing is broadcasting behavior.  Broadcasting behavior for operators is pretty well defined with non-assignment operators in numpy, the [documentation stating](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes
>   element-wise. It starts with the trailing dimensions, and works its
>   way forward. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1

Easy for a * b, but what about a *= b, or a[:] = b?  Assignment in numpy appears to follow *some* of the broadcasting rules, ie:

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
a = a.reshape(3,1,1,3)
b = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
b = b.reshape(1,1,3,3)

c = a * b # works!
a *= b # fails, non-broadcastable output operand with shape (1,1,3,3) doesn't match the broadcast shape (3,1,1,3)
a[:] = b #fails, could not broadcast input array from shape (1,1,3,3) into to shape (3,1,1,3)
b[:,:,:] = a[1,0,0,:] # works!
```

Now, I can intuitively understand some of the rules, why it wouldn't make sense to for some of these assignments.  The issue is that I see no ruleset governing broadcast on assignment as a whole. I assume it has something to do with the output location shape matching, though even that logic failed for the last working example (where they didn't).  The closest thing I can find is a single [statement in the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) (emphasis mine):

> As mentioned, one can select a subset of an array to assign to using a
>   single index, slices, and index and mask arrays. The value being
>   assigned to the indexed array must be shape consistent (**the same shape
>   or broadcastable to the shape the index produces**). For example, it is
>   permitted to assign a constant to a slice:

***What is the definition of "broadcastible to the shape" here?***

Comment: `broadcasting` does not change the shape/dims of the LHS, the `a` or `a[:]`.  If applying the rules to the RHS doesn't do the job, it raises the error.

Comment: @hpaulj what rules are we talking about?  In the above example, both a and b were valid for broadcasting, and technically would have been memory compatible, but could not be used in a broadcast assignment.  Yet the row assignment version theoretically should have subject to the same issues, but was able to be broadcast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (1,1,3,3) into to shape (3,1,1,3)

`b` with shape (1,1,3,3) can broadcast to (3,1,3,3) but not to (3,1,1,3).  The 3rd dim is `3`, and can't be changed to `1`.

When doing `a*=` and `a[:]=`, the shape of `a` does not change.

`a[1,0,0,:]` is (1,1,3) which can broadcast to (1,1,1,3) and on to (1,1,3,3).

With `c = a*b`, the broadcasting is:

```
(3,1,1,3) * (1,1,3,3) => (3,1,3,3)
```

One dim of `a` increases to 3, another dim of `b` also increases to 3.  With the binary operator `*` both arguments are broadcasted.  In assignment, only the RHS is.

Comment: So in other-words, if you are trying to broadcast b into a, each number in the shape of of b must be 1 or equal to the same dimension of of a?  Or i guess really the takeaway that if the resulting broadcast would have resulted in a change in size of the output, the assignment broadcast is invalid?

Comment: Okay I see from your edit, the point is only one is broadcast, if it doesn't fit in the output with the broadcasted dimensions, it isn't valid. Or it's kind of where the input and output shapes are already defined, and the broadcasted shape must match the output shape, or by definition it would result in a index error.